# How do I rm file from shell script whose name starts from TRAN followed by datetime stamp

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I need to remove a file from shell script whose name starts with `TRAN` followed by date time stamp.

```
ls -Al TRAN* | awk '{print $9}'
```

gives me the name of file on command line.
However, I cant seem to store it in a variable.

```
name=$(ls -Al TRAN* | awk '{print $9}')
```

on executing:

> syntax error at line 32: `name=$' unexpected

Please advise

Comment: You should mention which shell you're using for the script.

Comment: You have an error on a previous line (probably a missing parenthesis or something similar).

Comment: If you just want the name, why not just say `name=$(ls TRAN*)` ? Then there's just the name and nothing to parse.

Comment: syntax error at line 36: `name=$' unexpected

Answer (score 3):

Processing the output of `ls` is frowned upon because [it is quite fragile](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Use `find` instead:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'TRAN.*' -delete
```

Comment: I always like to include a [link to the ParsingLS page in Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) when explaining this.  Saves providing a detailed explanation about why it's fragile in the S.O. answer. :-)  Note also that you can use basic parameter expansion to identify the date -- `-name 'TRAN[0-9][0-9]etc'` works, though of course the OP hasn't told us what date format to look for.

Comment: @ghoti Yep, the link is useful indeed. Let me add it! I omitted to specify the date pattern since - as you said - the OP doesn't gave us information about how the date format will look like.

Comment: Also, if there are subdirectories, you'll want to limit traversal with `find -maxdepth 1` or just use `printf '%s\n' TRAN*` instead. Or directly `rm TRAN*` if the wildcard is guarateed to never match files you don't want to delete.

Comment: @tripleee Added the `-maxdepth 1` check. Note that `rm TRAN*` works only for a limited amount of files.

Comment: If `-delete` is not available with your version of `find`, use `-exec rm {} +` instead.

Comment: find path/R120files/TRA* -ok  rm -f {} \;
< rm ... /path/R120files/TRANCD21_080701 >?

On executing the file from script which is at same location: 
find: stat() error /home/fmfauntt/R120files/TRA*: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

name=`ls -l | grep 'TRAN' | awk '{print $9}'`;
This assignment worked
Thanks everyone!